# How to upload a picture base_64 coded into an HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, base64, esp32

I'm developing a webpage in HTML and PHP, which communicates with an Arduino board via a MYSQL database.

I'm having trouble with displaying pictures that are taken from the database. This is the HTML/PHP code from the page I am coding. It selects the last item from the table Video and removes the ID code. The picture in fact gets to the PHP, since I can display it as text, but I haven't managed to display it myself. Any idea?

```
<?php 
include("conectar.php");
$img = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM video ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($img); 

?>

<html>
    <style>
        body {
          background-image: url('fondo.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-attachment: fixed;
          background-size: 100% 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>CocoNet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="titulo">Cámara del Portero</h1>
        <br>
        <img src=<?php echo base64_encode(substr(implode($row),4,-1));?>>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="controlPortero.html">
            <input type="button" value="Volver">
        </a>


    </body>
</html>
```

When I go to the database and open the file uploaded, I get this. This is the picture coded on 64 base that I get from the Arduino board and upload to the database. The matter is that when I try to display it on the webpage, I get either this photo icon that means the file couldn't be displayed or a blank text space.

This is the last thing I have to solve to end up with the webpage. After reading a bit more, I found out that this is caused because the file is too big. Do you have any idea about how to solve it?

```
===Base de datos coconet

== Estructura de tabla para la tabla video

|------
|Columna|Tipo|Nulo|Predeterminado
|------
|//**ID**//|int(11)|No|
|Video|longblob|No|
== Volcado de datos para la tabla video
|29|data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Comment: Why are you using `implode` and `substr` to access an array item? And why are you base64 encoding already base64 encoded data? You are also missing quotes. Seems you are doing this completely blind without any debugging attempt.

Comment: the subsrt is used because when the array is taken from the database, they come with some data related to the auto incremental ID, which are removed. The implode was to try to somehow display the image. How do you recommend me to do it?

Comment: `$row['Video']`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED :,D

In the end, it was just that I didn't choose which array cell to display. I just had to set as the img sources the array which fetched the image on the cell 0.

```
<?php 
include("conectar.php");
$img = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT Video FROM video ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($img);

?>

<html>
    <style>
        body {
          background-image: url('fondo.jpg');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-attachment: fixed;
          background-size: 100% 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>CocoNet</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="titulo">Cámara del Portero</h1>
        <br>
        <img src='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>'>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="controlPortero.html">
            <input type="button" value="Volver">
        </a>


    </body>
</html>
```